# How to set MediaContollerto MediaPlayer in android?

Tags: android, media-player, mediacontroller

How to set `MediaContoller` to `MediaPlayer` in android and I want to show it permanently  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the MediaController class and programmatically set an instance of it to a VideoView class. Here's a good example showing how:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8409863/1369222