# android - overriding back button causes volume buttons stop working

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-button, android-event

I'm trying to override Back button to stop an audio player and close media player activity, but I noticed that volume buttons are not working anymore. I imagine there is a mistake in overriding code. PS. in my `MediaController` I override `hide()` method to always show controls.

```
mediaController = new MediaController(this)

{
    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //do nothing
    }


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

        if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;

            }
            super.hide();

            Activity a = (Activity)getContext();
            a.finish();

        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: I have had the same issue, see my answer :)

Comment: i have updated the ans try that

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is in dispatchKeyEvent():

You are using `return true` for all the HW Keys and this stops all keys from responding,

whereas you should be using

```
return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
```

For keys other than Back Key.

### So your code should be something like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        } 

        finish();
        return true;
    }
    **return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);**
}
```

Comment: I understood what you mean and your code let me use volume buttons as aspected, but when I launch the activity and press back button it crashes with this message: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 2):

You could overide [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should use like this

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

        if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            } 

            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Out the code from method or try :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     if (mediaPlayer != null) {
          mediaPlayer.reset();
          mediaPlayer.release();
          mediaPlayer = null;
     } 
   finish();
}
```

or

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            } 

           finish();
           return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, I edited the code, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Did  you tried this check it once it may solve your issue

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
         if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            } 

           finish();


    }
```

Comment: where did you get `event`

Comment: why you need  to cast context to Activity. onBackPressed is a method of Activity. So what is missing is a call to super.onBackPressed()

Comment: ok that is also right @blackbelt he want to finish the activity

Comment: doesn't work, I edited the code, please have a look.