# Want to Keep Media controllers visible in VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using android video for my app and I don't want media controller to hide any help

here is my Java code

import com.example.androidhive.R;

public class Activity_Webview extends Activity{

```
ProgressDialog pDialog;
VideoView videoview;
WebView webView;
String url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask
    // Create a progressbar
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity_Webview.this);
    // Set progressbar title
    pDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
    // Set progressbar message
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Show progressbar
    pDialog.show();
    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(videoview.getContext());
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        url = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            videoview.start();
        }
    });
}
```

}
This is my XML Code

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/VideoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7w53.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458529/mediacontroller-always-show-on-android .... please check this link.

Answer (score 0):

`mediacontroller.show(0);`

and the source code below :

```
/**
 * Show the controller on screen. It will go away
 * automatically after 'timeout' milliseconds of inactivity.
 * @param timeout The timeout in milliseconds. Use 0 to show
 * the controller until hide() is called.
 */
public void show(int timeout) {
    if (!mShowing && mAnchor != null) {
        setProgress();
        if (mPauseButton != null) {
            mPauseButton.requestFocus();
        }
        disableUnsupportedButtons();
        updateFloatingWindowLayout();
        mWindowManager.addView(mDecor, mDecorLayoutParams);
        mShowing = true;
    }
    updatePausePlay();

    // cause the progress bar to be updated even if mShowing
    // was already true.  This happens, for example, if we're
    // paused with the progress bar showing the user hits play.
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);

    if (timeout != 0 && !mAccessibilityManager.isTouchExplorationEnabled()) {
        mHandler.removeMessages(FADE_OUT);
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(FADE_OUT);
        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, timeout);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to hind weather i touch it or not I just want it to be alive all the time and never hide.